# Find the name all tables in DBF database

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, dbf

I'm trying to find out the names of the `tables.DBF`, which are in a hard drive directory.

Subsequently, I need to know the names of their columns, but even the names of the tables I do not know how to find out. Standard SQL tools do not work, it's logical. The script is run on the site under IIS (win server 2008), VBScript. For the connection, I use the driver: AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.

The selection from the specific tables is working, create, delete the table - it works. Connection code:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE=1251%>
<%
Function OpenDBFConn(Path)
   Dim Conn: Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Conn.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                         "Data Source=" & Path & ";" & _
                         "Extended Properties=""DBASE IV;"";"
   Set OpenDBFConn = Conn
End Function
Dim DBConn
Set DBConn = OpenDBFConn("C:\update")
Dim Lel
Set Lel = DBConn.Execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'")
%>
```

The script result:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

This is logical. Here, the methods for accessing the system table will not work, because they are not. Question - how do I know the names of the tables in the 'Update' folder? Screenshot of the folders:

[image: Screenshot of the folders]

Comment: That's not VB.NET.  Is this an ASP.NET app written in VB.NET or is it actually an ASP app, which uses VBScript?  As for your SQL, it looks like it's for SQL Server and maybe Access.  You should be searching for something specific to dBase.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider works for DBF databases. Compare the DBF/Fox Pro section on https://www.connectionstrings.com/ and try that.

Comment: this connection works, I through it unloaded data from specific tables

Comment: For tables name, use Scripting.FileSystemObject (to find all .dbf files in the folder).

Comment: For column name, is this works with dBase?
    `Set rsTable = conn.Execute(sqlText)
    fieldsCount = rsTable.Fields.Count
    for i = 0 to fieldsCount - 1
     columnName = rsTable.Fields(i).Name)
    next`

Comment: Thx, I refused this method of working with ".dbf", I prescribe the tables explicitly. By the way, the answer to this question is on another forum, though the problem is not as solved as I wanted, but this is also the right move. Link - http://www.cyberforum.ru/vba/thread2326706.html#post12934643

Answer (score 0):

1) Table names. As it's already mentioned, get table names (i.e. M1072R, M10201, etc.) by using [FileSystemObject](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_files.asp):

```
Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fo=fs.GetFolder("C:\update")

For Each x in fo.files
     If LCase(fs.GetExtensionName(x.path)) = "dbf" Then 
        Response.Write fs.GetBaseName(x.path) & ";"
    End if
Next
```

2) Column names:

```
'Dim Lel
'Set Lel = DBConn.Execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'")

Set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open "M1072R", DBConn 
'-- where M1072R is your table/dbf file

For Each f In rs.Fields
  Response.Write "Column=" & f.Name & ";"  
Next
```

Another way to get columns is to use [OpenSchema](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_conn_openschema.asp)

```
Set rs=DBConn.OpenSchema(4, Array(Null, Null, "M1072R")) 
'-- where M1072R is your table/dbf file, 
'-- 4 stands for adSchemaColumns

Do While Not rs.EOF
  Response.Write "Column=" & rs.Fields("COLUMN_NAME").Value & ";"
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

OLEDB 4.0, ADO, VBScript, ASP Classic

Table names in Access are accessible through the recordset obtained using the OpenSchema method with the adSchemaTables parameter.

however in VBScript the enumerated variable is not defined, so you have to create it inside VBScript with a variable and set it to 20, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/schemaenum

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%OPTION EXPLICIT%>

Dim objConn
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

With objConn

  .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
  .ConnectionString =  "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("\test.mdb")
  .Open

End With

Dim objRS
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Const adSchemaTables = 20 ' SchemaEnum Values (Returns the tables (including views) defined in the catalog that are accessible to a given user)

Set objRS = objConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)

if objRS.EOF then

  response.write "<div>adSchemaTables: empty!</div>"
  objRS.Close()
  Set objRS = Nothing

else

objRS.MoveFirst
While Not objRS.EOF

  response.write objRS.Fields("TABLE_NAME") & "<br />"

  objRS.MoveNext
wend
    
objRS.Close()
Set objRS = Nothing

end if

%>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).